# How to change the file location of Overwatch Logs and Settings

Tags: overwatch

```
C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Documents\Overwatch
```

Is currently my save location for overwatch settings and logs but due to OneDrive, I am receiving a sync error as shown below.

Does anyone know of how to change the settings file location?

[image: Save Location of Overwatch Settings]

Comment: You should be able to remove that folder from synchronization via OneDrive settings, this sort of solves your problem